# How to override comment field in system.xml in magento2?

Tags: magento2, system.xml

I have override system.xml file.

My label is overridden but comment field is not overridden. It's still take from core file. Any help should be appreciated. Thanks.

**Core system.xml file code**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../Magento/Config/etc/system_file.xsd">
<system>
    <tab id="lsc" translate="label" sortOrder="100">
        <label>SLI Systems LSC</label>
    </tab>
    <section id="sli_feed_generation" translate="label" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <class>separator-top</class>
        <label>Feed Generation</label>
        <tab>lsc</tab>
        <resource>Sli_Feed::config_feed</resource>

        <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>General</label>
            <field id="enabled" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Enabled</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>
            <field id="log_level" translate="label comment" type="select" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Log Level</label>
                <comment>Please set to "Debug" if SLI support is required.</comment>
                <source_model>SLI\Feed\Model\Config\Source\Log</source_model>
            </field>
            <field id="version" translate="label" type="label" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Version</label>
                <frontend_model>SLI\Feed\Block\System\Config\Version</frontend_model>
            </field>
        </group>

        <group id="feed" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Feed Settings</label>
            <field id="advanced_pricing" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Advanced Pricing</label>
                <comment>Enable if need advanced prices from: Catalog Price Rules, Group or Tiered Pricing.</comment>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>
            <field id="include_out_of_stock" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Include Out of Stock Items</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>
            <field id="generate" translate="label comment" type="button" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Generate Feed</label>
                <frontend_model>SLI\Feed\Block\System\Config\Generate</frontend_model>
                <comment>Manually generates feed. If FTP is enabled, also sends the feed.</comment>
            </field>
        </group>

        <group id="ftp" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>FTP Settings</label>
            <field id="enabled" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Enabled</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>
            <field id="user" translate="label comment" type="text" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>FTP User</label>
                <comment>Provided by SLI.</comment>
                <depends>
                    <field id="enabled">1</field>
                </depends>
            </field>
            <field id="password" translate="label comment" type="obscure" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>FTP Password</label>
                <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted</backend_model>
                <comment>Provided by SLI.</comment>
                <depends>
                    <field id="enabled">1</field>
                </depends>
            </field>
            <field id="host" translate="label comment" type="text" sortOrder="4" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>FTP Host</label>
                <comment>Provided by SLI.</comment>
                <depends>
                    <field id="enabled">1</field>
                </depends>
            </field>
            <field id="upload_path" translate="label comment" type="text" sortOrder="5" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>FTP Upload Path</label>
                <comment>Provided by SLI.</comment>
                <depends>
                    <field id="enabled">1</field>
                </depends>
            </field>
        </group>

        <group id="product" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="4" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Product Attributes</label>
            <field id="attributes_select" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Attributes to include</label>

                <frontend_model>SLI\Feed\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FeedAttributesConfig</frontend_model>
                <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized</backend_model>

                <comment>
                    <![CDATA[
                    The following attributes are automatically added to the feed: <br />
                    <ul style="margin-left: 2em;">
                        <li><small>attribute_set_id</small></li>
                        <li><small>categories</small></li>
                        <li><small>child_ids</small></li>
                        <li><small>created_at</small></li>
                        <li><small>entity_id</small></li>
                        <li><small>final_price</small></li>
                        <li><small>has_options</small></li>
                        <li><small>is_salable</small></li>
                        <li><small>is_virtual</small></li>
                        <li><small>max_price</small></li>
                        <li><small>min_price</small></li>
                        <li><small>minimal_price</small></li>
                        <li><small>name</small></li>
                        <li><small>price</small></li>
                        <li><small>special_from_date</small></li>
                        <li><small>special_price</small></li>
                        <li><small>special_to_date</small></li>
                        <li><small>request_path</small></li>
                        <li><small>required_options</small></li>
                        <li><small>sku</small></li>
                        <li><small>tax_class_id</small></li>
                        <li><small>tier_price</small></li>
                        <li><small>type_id</small></li>
                        <li><small>updated_at</small></li>
                        <li><small>url_key</small></li>
                        <li><small>visibility</small></li>
                        <li><small>image</small></li>
                    </ul>
                    ]]>
                </comment>
            </field>
        </group>
    </section>
</system>
```

**my custom system.xml code**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
<system>
    <section id="sli_feed_generation" >
        <group id="product">
            <label>Product Attributes AData</label>
            <field id="attributes_select" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <comment>
                    <![CDATA[
                    The following attributes are automatically added to the feed: <br />
                    <ul style="margin-left: 2em;">
                        <li><small>attribute_set_id</small></li>
                        <li><small>categories</small></li>
                     </ul>
                    ]]>
                </comment>
            </field>
        </group>
    </section>
</system>
```

please see:
[image]

module.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Tatva_SLIFeed" setup_version="0.0.1">
    <sequence>
        <module name="SLI_Feed" />
    </sequence>
</module>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Vendor/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
<system>
<section id="sli_feed_generation" >
<group id="product">
<label>Product Attributes AData</label>
<field id="attributes_select" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
<comment>
<![CDATA[
The following attributes are automatically added to the feed: <br />
<ul style="margin-left: 2em;">
<li><small>attribute_set_id</small></li>
<li><small>categories</small></li>
</ul>
]]>
</comment>
</field>
</group>
</section>
</system>
```

> Vendor/ModuleName/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Vendor_YourModule" setup_version="1.0.0">
<sequence>
<module name="Core_ModuleName"/>
</sequence>
</module>
</config>
```

**Note : Core_ModuleName is overridden module name.**

Hope, It will helpful for you.

Comment: What you suggest is i have already tried.
it's not working for comment field

If i am changing label it worked!!!

Comment: I use your comment in my code and test. It's update successfully. Remove var & generated folder and check it.

Comment: I have added screenshot please check
I have removed all cache folder and generated folder

Comment: what is your magento version?

Comment: And please make sure that in module.xml this is correct or not. <module name="Sli_Feed"/>

Comment: magento 2.2.5
Yes my module also working and excepting comment field all other fields are overridden

Comment: please find module.xml